# Retrieve UserId of @mention user from chatter post in Apex

Tags: apex, chatter, user-record, feeditem, connect-api

Is there a way to retrieve the user id of @mention user from chatter post in Apex? We can write a before insert trigger on feeditem, but when we display the body (which has @mention user) it simply displays as text. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 11):

You can use the new Chatter API in Apex to do this. It's in developer preview currently and is on by default in all Developer Edition orgs. (Note: It went GA in Summer '13.)

Here's an example of how to use it:

```
String communityId = null;
String feedItemId = 'YOUR_FEEDITEM_ID';

ConnectApi.FeedItem feedItem = ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.getFeedItem(communityId, feedItemId);
List<ConnectApi.MessageSegment> messageSegments = feedItem.body.messageSegments;
for (ConnectApi.MessageSegment messageSegment : messageSegments) {
    if (messageSegment instanceof ConnectApi.MentionSegment) {
        ConnectApi.MentionSegment mentionSegment = (ConnectApi.MentionSegment) messageSegment;
        System.debug('Mentioned user name: ' + mentionSegment.name);
        System.debug('Mentioned user id: ' + mentionSegment.user.id);
    }
}
```

Link: [API documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_connect_api.htm) for the [ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/connectAPI_ChatterFeedsClass.htm) class.

Comment: now to access user record related information such as user id, use `mentionSegment.record.id` instead of `mentionSegment.user.id`

Answer (score 2):

Here is the update of the code for 2023, getFeedItem is no longer support in latest API version.

```
String communityId = null;
String feedItemId = 'YOUR_FEEDITEM_ID';

ConnectApi.FeedElement feedItem = ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.getFeedElement(communityId, feedItemId);
List<ConnectApi.MessageSegment> messageSegments = feedItem.body.messageSegments;
for (ConnectApi.MessageSegment messageSegment : messageSegments) {
    if (messageSegment instanceof ConnectApi.MentionSegment) {
        ConnectApi.MentionSegment mentionSegment = (ConnectApi.MentionSegment) messageSegment;
        System.debug('Mentioned user name: ' + mentionSegment.name);
        System.debug('Mentioned user id: ' + mentionSegment.record.id);
    }
}
```